# non numeric value of html5 number field

Tags: javascript, html

I want to do my own validation of a number field but element.value does not return anything in chrome if the content is alphabetical.  Is there anything I can do to get this value? I thought setting 'novalidate' on the form would prevent his from happening but it doesn't. This means I cannot tell the difference between someone entering nothing and entering a string of characters.

http://jsfiddle.net/Y8dty/5/

```
<form novalidate='true'>
    <input type='number' id='ex' />
</form>
$('ex').observe('blur', function() {
    alert($('ex').value);                            
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns an empty string when it's non-numeric. [You can do loose comparison](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8dty/6/).

```
var ex = $('ex');
ex.observe('blur', function() {
    var value = ex.value;
    if(value) console.log('value is '+value);
    else console.log('something is wrong here');
});
```

Comment: so there is no way to tell the difference between the input being empty and the input containing a string?

Comment: @baddev even if you check in the DOM inspector, non-numeric inputs have blank values.

Comment: ok, thanks.  So is it just an error that is likely to get fixed that this works in Firefox/IE?